# how to refresh a page automatically when another web page is closed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web page which has a dropdown in ViewData.aspx. On click of a link it redirects to another page where data for the dropdown can be added in AddData.aspx. On close of AddData.aspx page the ViewData.aspx is not getting refreshed with the newly added data for dropdown. Currently i am pressing F5. How to achieve this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a named window and java-script, but i'm not sure how this works with newer browsers. Look here: http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html for this method.

Alternatively you could use a jQueryModal Window or something like that and reload your dropdown or the full page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not redirecting the user to AddView, but opening AddView in a new browser window as a type of popup. If that is what you're doing it wouldn't recommend it.

Instead of that solution I would suggest either to:

- make AddData a user control and include it in the ViewData page
  (maybe within a hidden div as a modal popup) or
- make ViewData actually redirect to the AddData page in the same browser instance and have a button on the AddData which redirects back to the ViewData.

If you really need the ViewData and AddData to be viewable at the same time in different windows then you could programmatically "lock" the Viewdata page at the point when AddData is triggered and then request the user to press an "update" button on ViewData which would reload the ViewData page.

Comment: the 2 option currently i have a close button in the AddData page which refresh the ViewData but when user clicks the close in the browser i am not able to refresh the page.

Comment: @swathi If you are doing Option 2, you have to show the AddData.aspx in same window not in different window. As **iandayman** suggests Put a button on AddData.aspx page and on clicking that button redirect to View page

Comment: @RVG the current implementation is that AddData.aspx is a separate window.